# Python ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am somewhat familiar with Python's ArgumentParser. I have two python scripts currently. The first does not take any arguments, the second takes arguments.

Script1: config_init.py

Script2: config_rest.py arg1 arg2

I want to write a 3rd script which should behave like this

Script3:

When I want it to execute `config_init`, I want the 3rd script to be executed as `config_setup.py init`

When I want it to execute `config_rest.py arg1 arg2`, I want it to be excuted as `config_setup arg1 arg2`

I am not sure how do I do this because the arguments are optional or positional now? Basically if someone gives the argument `init`, I do not care about more arguments as that executes Script1

If someone gives `arg1 arg2`, I want to make sure after `arg1`, `arg2` is given and I execute Script2

Can I be pointed to some sample for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use named params in your third script.

```
config_setup.py --init=True

config_setup.py --arg1=arg1 --arg2=arg2
```

You will need to write code to validate your params. Another approach is to use init as the default.

```
config_setup.py  # calls config_init
config_setup.py -arg1 -arg2  # calls config_rest with args.
```

Comment: but won't named params make the params as optional? May I ask for sample snippet to get a clear idea?

Comment: You will need to write extra code to validate the params.

Comment: and extra code to make them exclusive also like "init" or "arg1 and arg2"?